# Where are the nuget authentication packages for aspnet core 3?

Tags: authentication, nuget, .net-core-3.0

I have a custom authentication component that is working with net core 2.2. I've started migrating the project to net core 3, but it seems like MS hasn't updated the authentication Nuget packages.

Until now, I was referencing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` package. The package still exists, but hasn't been updated to net core 3.0 (it's still on the 2.2 version).

I can't keep using it because net core 3.0 has moved the `RequestPathBaseCookieBuilder` type to a different namespace (so, at runtime, I'll get a tyoe loading exception). A quick search shows that only the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` has been updated to net core 3.0 (and if I add it to my project, then my component to work without any issues).

Anyone knows why MS hasn't still updated the other security nuget packages to version 3? Is there anyway to solve this without using the openidconnect nuget package (I'm only using it because it was the first that was updated and it will bring the correct Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication assembly that I need for my project)?

Comment: If only some packages were updated, the ASP.NET Core templates wouldn't work at all. That's especially true for a major package like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication`. ASP.NET 3.0 is a major version so breaking changes are expected. The namespaces and even packages have been rearranged.

Comment: Create a new `webapp` project with the authentication settings you want and inspect the code.

Comment: The new aspnet core projects aren't affected because they're using the new SDK  moniker approach (instead of using the old meta package strategy). If you do a quick nuget search, you'll see that most of the authentication nuget packages are still on the 2.2 version (with the openidconnect package being the exception).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was 10 minutes too late, but you posted the answer as a comment, rather than an answer, and I like questions having answers so I stop opening them when browsing the question search results.

Anyway, as you discovered, .NET Core 3.0 no longer uses packages for base class libraries (BCLs). Instead, they're just part of the SDK, so by targeting `netcoreapp3.0` or `netstandard2.1`, all BCLs are just available. This should eliminate a lot of problems that earlier .NET Core projects had, particularly when referencing .NET Standard 1.x assemblies from `netcoreapp2.x` tfms. Although the largest benefit will be when all referenced packages target `netstandard2.1` or `netcoreapp3.0` or above.

Comment: The project that has the custom authentication middleware is targeting net core 3, but, unfortunately, it's still complaining about the types (AuthenticationHandler et al) I'm using as base classes...ie, it's still required to add reference to the nuget packages...

Comment: ASP.NET Core types are pulled in when using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, check your csproj. However, it appears problematic to use this SDK when trying to create a classlib. This might be a question best asked to the aspnet team.

Comment: hello again. I'm not building a web site. I'm building a custom authentication assembly that should be used in several web sites (library project)... currently I'm targeting net core 3, just like the default openid connect assembly thats built by Ms...

Comment: The question about where ASP.NET Core classes, like `AuthenticationHandler`, are defined, the answer is in the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK. How to use this in a package or classlib, I don't know. From quick experimentation, it's not as easy as creating classlibs for `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` projects. If no one else answers this question, a new question or github issue might be useful, but with more specific wording/keywords/tags. I can't answer, but I can help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @zivkan. I'll ask in github then.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so finally got it. The [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference) is to use the `FrameworkReference` element with the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` meta package.